# Session cookie in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, session-cookies

Is there an easy way to manage session cookies with GAE? I just need to auth the user and such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Users API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/) to authenticate users - either using Google accounts, or OpenID. If you want sessions without user login, there are a number of libraries, such as [gaesessions](https://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).

Comment: The question is about personal registration, no google login. Geasessions and any other libraries dont work with python 2.7 and they will be obsolete more soon that we believe

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is for me the easiest way using Python 2.7.

```
import Cookie
value_session = "userid (encrypted);time of login"
name_cookie = "sessioncookie"
expires = 2629743 # 1 month in seconds

D = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
D["name_cookie"] = value_session
D["name_cookie"]["path"] = "/"
D["name_cookie"]["expires"] = expires
print(D)
```

Comment: Using this, an attacker can simply modify the userid in the cookie, and be instantly logged in as a different user.

Comment: You right Nick, but of course the userid has to be a hash using the ip, browser identity and the user id of the application. Everything below of a encryption for example sha512. What do you think about that? Do you have any other way to do it?

Comment: I think you should avoid inventing your own sessions library, and use an existing one, such as Beaker. It's already dealt with these security issues.